# Javascript Array Issues

Tags: javascript, arrays

The task at hand;

> Return true if the string in the first element of the array contains
>   all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array.
>
> For example, ['hello', 'Hello'], should return true because all of the
>   letters in the second string are present in the first, ignoring case.
>
> The arguments ['hello', 'hey'] should return false because the string
>   'hello' does not contain a 'y'.
>
> Lastly, ['Alien', 'line'], should return true because all of the
>   letters in 'line' are present in 'Alien'.

My attempted solution that isn't working;

```
function mutation(arr) {
  if (arr[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(arr[1].toLowerCase()) >= 0){
    return true;
  }else{
   return false;
  }
  return arr;
}

mutation(['hello', 'hey']);
```

Can someone please explain to me why it isn't working. I am not looking for an answer just an explanation so that I can understand better.

Many thanks

Comment: `return arr;` will never ever execute.. at least on this planet

Comment: Convert the string into a character array by calling `String.prototype.split()`, sorting each array and comparing each element until you reach the end of the smallest array. You return `false` immediately if the comparison of characters fails.

Comment: Please define "isn't working".

Comment: The code I write will be run under various tests to see if it meets the given conditions. So far my code meets some and not others. All the instructions I have been given are posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#id').click(function() {
    var arr = ['hello','hey'];
    var isExist = false;
    for (i = 0;i < arr[1].length; i++) {
        if(arr[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(arr[1][i].toLowerCase()) >= 0)
            isExist = true;
        else {
            isExist = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isExist)
        alert('true');  // In case of all chars of 2nd present in 1st arr
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your output you have to check all the characters of array second string with array first string. For this you have to check all characters are available or not in the first string, not using the direct string. If we use strings directly, it will look for total string not for the characters.

Try the following:

```
var arr =  ['Alien', 'line'];
var arr1 = ['hello','hey'];
var arr2 = ['hello','Hello'];
function mutation(arr) {
  var str1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var str2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  var o = false;
  for (var i=0;i<str2.length;i++) {
    o = (str1.indexOf(str2[i]) !== -1);
    if (!o) break;
  }

  return o;
}

console.log('first arr : ', mutation(arr));
console.log('second arr :', mutation(arr1));
console.log('third arr :', mutation(arr2));
```

Comment: Well, that's not going to work. It's recalculating `o` each time through the loop, so `o` will be the result of the last character matching or not. What you need to do is return `false` the minute you find a missing character.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks, i forgot about that, I'll modify it :).

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is that, you are converting first element to lower case and than trying to find the second element in first array.
your solution will work for the cases where the whole second element exists in first element as a sub string or both elements are exactly same.
for example it'll work for following examples

> ['hello', 'Hello']
>
> ['hello', 'ell']
>
> ['hello', 'He']

But it will not work when letters in second string are shuffled first string. for following examples your solution will fail.

> ['Alien', 'line']
>
> ['hello', 'elo']
>
> ['hello', 'Hol']

**If whole second word does not exists as it is in first word your solution will not work.**

Let me know if this is helpful. i'll provide you the solution if you need.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer correctly states, your code does not work because it's looking in the first string for the second string, in its entirety, with the letters in the same order. Instead, you need to look at each letter in the second string individually and check that it's in the first string.

We'll adopt the strategy of "Programming in English and going backward". The English for the overall problem is:

> Does every letter to check match?

We can write this in JavaScript as

```
letters_to_check . every(matches)
```

We can calculate `letters_to_check` as `input[1].toLowerCase().split('')`.

Now we have to write the `matches` function, which can be expressed in English as

> Is the letter found in the string to check against?

So we write

```
function matches(letter) { return string_to_heck_against.search(letter); }
```

`string_to_check_against` is of course `input[0]`.

The entire program is thus:

```
function mutation(input) {

  // Check if a letter is in the string to be checked against.
  function matches(letter) { return string_to_check_against.search(letter); }

  var string_to_check_against = input[0].toLowerCase();
  var string_to_check         = input[1].toLowerCase();
  var letters_to_check        = string_to_check.split('');

  return letters_to_check . every(matches);

}
```

If you are programming in ES6, this could be written as

```
function mutation([source, target]) {
  return target   .
    toLowerCase() .
    split('')     .
    every(letter => source.toLowerCase().search(letter));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code. You can check. The idea is to transfer both strings in the array to lowercase. Then we compare both strings together.

I take every single letter from the shorter string, then use the indexOf function to check if it's in the longer string. Every time there is a match, the valule no1 or no2 will increase.

If the value of no1 or no2 equal with the length of the shorter string, it means all the letters in the shorter string is inside the longer string.

```
function mutation(arr) {

  // transfer both strings in the array to lower case
  var val1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var val2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();

  // check if val2 is shorter than val1
  if(val1.length >= val2.length){
    var no1 = 0;
  // Check every if any letter in val2 is in val1
    for(var i = 0; i < val2.length; i++){
      if(val1.indexOf(val2[i]) != -1){
  // plus 1 if there is a match
        no1++;
      }
    }
    // check if the value of no1 equals to length of val2
    if(no1 == val2.length){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }else if(val2.length > val1.length){
    var no2 = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < val1.length; j++){
      if(val2.indexOf(val1[j]) != -1){
        no2++;
      }
    }

    if(no2 == val1.length){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }        
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some commentary along with your answer rather than simply providing a wall of code? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Suever . I'm so happy when make it works. Sorry about that. I added some comments. Hope that you will understand.